# Detect URL query string encoding

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, query-string, ascii

On a request URL, I can get the query string `?dir=Documents%20partag%C3%A9s` or `?dir=Documents%20partag%E9s`. I think the first one is UTF-8 and the second is ASCII.

The real string is : `Documents partagés`

So, I have a PHP script (in UTF-8) and what I want to do, is to detect if the query string is ASCII or UTF-8, and if ASCII, convert it to UTF-8.

I tried with `mb_` functions, but the query string is always detected as ASCII and urldecode version of query string as UTF-8.

How can I achieve this? Note that Wikipedia has a similar function -it encodes itself `%E9` to `%C3%A9`.

Comment: Maybe this comment on php.net can help you out: http://at2.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-check-encoding.php#95289

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`E9` is 233 in decimal. It is not a valid ASCII byte (0-127 only), but it is `é` in ISO-8859-1 (Latin1). When using `mb_convert_encoding`, you can specify multiple encodings (e.g.: UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1).

This should fix it:

```
mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8,ISO-8859-1');
```

With the following script:

```
$str1 = 'Documents%20partag%E9s';
$str2 = 'Documents%20partag%C3%A9s';
var_dump(mb_convert_encoding(urldecode($str1), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8,ISO-8859-1'));
var_dump(mb_convert_encoding(urldecode($str2), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8,ISO-8859-1'));
```

I get:

```
string(19) "Documents partagés"
string(19) "Documents partagés"
```

Comment: `urldecode` will decode `%E9` to the *byte* with the value 0xE9 regardless what character this byte may represent.

Comment: That’s also wrong. A byte is a byte is a byte. A string is also just a sequence of bytes, they are just data and not information. Only when interpreted with a particular character encoding these bytes are not just bytes but they also represent characters, thus information. And `urldecode` does only turn the `%93` into the byte with the value 0x93. That’s it. Only when interpreted with a particular character encoding (like ISO 8859-1) that byte represents a character within that character set (as long as that byte sequence is valid).

Comment: The US-ASCII character set has only 128 characters (encoded with 0x00–0x7F). Any other byte is invalid.

Comment: @Gumbo: Wait, that's true. I think I'm mixing all my charsets suddenly. Nevermind then.